# find the number of all possible combinations with conflicts

Tags: combinations, conflict

I am trying to solve an optimization problem, but first I have to find the number of all possible combinations of n elements but considering some conflicts. A possible example could be:

elements: {1,2,3,4}
conflicts: {1,2},{3,4}

The term "conflict" means that the numbers that belong to the same conflict set must not be allocated into the same combination. Also the conflict sets are not always disjoint and the elements in each conflict set are always two.

Until now I only found how all possible combinations can be calculated, that is 2^n.

Thank you.

Comment: More info please. Have you tried any code/language?
Consider ordering elements and conflicts for faster comparision.

Comment: No I didn't ,what I'm searching at the moment is the NUMBER of possible combinations.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the number of subsets of a given set subject to the constraint that they don't contain as subsets any of a given list of subsets. Are the forbidden subsets disjoint (like {1,2} and {3,4}) in your example)? If so -- counting them seems fairly straightforward since any valid conflict-free subset would be uniquely expressible as a subset of the complement of the union of the conflict sets together with a series of *proper* subsets of the conflict sets. If the conflict sets include non-disjoint sets (e.g. {1,2} and {1,4}) counting them is tricky

Comment: Hi John, so in my optimization problem the conflict sets are not disjoint. For example :
elements:{1,2,3,4,5,6}
conflict sets:{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{2,6}

Comment: If they are not disjoint then it seems likely that the principle of inclusion/exclusion needs to be used -- which seldom leads to compact formulas.

Comment: Are the conflict sets always of cardinality 2? That would simplify things dramatically.

Comment: Could you be more specific, I red this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle on Wikipedia but I don't see how I can come to a solution.

Comment: exactly, always in pairs of two.

Comment: I can't be more specific about inclusion/exclusion -- which is more of a strategy than a directly useful formula. That was little more than a hunch. The part about pairs of 2 seems crucial. Perhaps you can edit your question to reflect it. I'll give it some thought tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conflict sets can be modeled as edges in a graph. You are asking for the number of independent vertex sets in a graph

> An independent vertex set of a graph G is a subset of the vertices such that no two vertices in the subset represent an edge of G
>   - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependentVertexSet.html

The above link also refers to something called the *independence polynomial* which can be used to count such things -- though this is useful only if the conflict graph has a nice structure. The general problem of determining the number of independent sets is known to be #P-complete (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete for a definition of this complexity class) so there is little chance that your question has a simple answer. Markov-chain techniques have been applied to *approximate* this number in some cases. See http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221590282_Approximately_Counting_Up_To_Four_(Extended_Abstract)

Comment: This link is really helpfull, however the question now is, how can you know which graph is the right one in respect to your instance of data or problem.

Comment: Seems like you are in deep waters here. The good news is that there is a sizable literature related to the problem. The bad news is that the literature doesn't contain the sort of simple formula or algorithm you were hoping for. I've edited my answer (which you can accept if you want) to reflect this.